# Updating ListView by notifydataSetChanged, has to use runOnUiThread?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

So i have this ListView, that uses my own custom arrayadapter.  It works great, getting data from the database etc, but after its set there is no updating it.  I have this activity that does something for result and when it comes back I call this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);          
        if(requestCode==1899)
        {       
            //a new client was added to the list...
            try {
                clients = (ArrayList<ClientsData>) clientsDataDao.queryForAll();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }                           
            theClients.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this is not working here                           
            showClientDetails(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex); //update other fragment.
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't actually do anything.  I did investigate further and I guess it has to be called on the UI Thread?  but I am in a FragmentActivity and I am not sure how to do this?  I might have to make a runnable thread and call it from there?  Haven't done much with threads so not sure, any one have good (concise and complete) examples on how to do this?  or is this even my problem?

(Note:  I switched to ORM Lite, before this i had at this particular spot a `SimpleCursorAdapter` that I could update after calling a `.requery` on my cursor and then the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

EDIT:

Okay so after a few comments I investigated the AsyncTask route...:

```
private class addViewsToList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                theClients.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }         
    }
```

and in my `onActivityCreated`:

```
new addViewsToList().execute();
```

and on my `onActivityResult(...)`:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);          
        if(requestCode==1899)
        {       
            //a new client was added to the list...
            try {
                clients = (ArrayList<ClientsData>) clientsDataDao.queryForAll();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }       
                            //do I have to reset the adapter?   
            setListAdapter(theClients);             
                        showClientDetails(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex);
        }
```

Still no update to the list...

So I demonstrated I have no clue what I am doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have to make Runnable.

How? Refeed the adapter where you update the new data (I assume you want to change something in the listview) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the runnable. Indeed you need `runOnUIThread()` because you are triggering updates on the ui. Or use `AsyncTask` where you update the listview either in `onPostExecute()` or `onProgessUpdate()` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am not sure how to go about doing this.  I saw one example for the runOnUIThread but couldn't figure out where to go about doing this in a FragmentActivity

Comment: I guess its the same like non-fragment activities, since the fragment has its own lifecycle, so UI updates are done the same way. I don't know if you are using ListFragment, but this might be useful to read 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: For one acticivity I am using listfragment.   Though others I am using fragments by themselves.  If I create a thread in each listfragment or fragment....then ill have that many threads running?

Comment: Oh and by refeed you mean a call to `setListAdapter(theClients);` ?

Comment: By refeeding i meant cursor = new xAdapter(), new instance of the cursor with the new data. And for the first question threads will be run whenever you start them. I mean there will be no more that 2 running...I hope you get my idea. Sorry for the delayed reply, I was sleeping,

Comment: cursor not the one you use for the database. The one for the listview (if you are using)

Comment: yah I am using a custom cursor adapter.  I will try that and do that and try it again using my async task above.

Comment: Well that did it, I set theClients adapter = new CustomClientAdapter (that I made) and it worked!  Thanks for your time on this, I am using it with an AsyncTask and hope there is no performance or threading issues down the road going that route.

Comment: Just mind the locking of the database when you are threading, I mean for concurrent threads access to database when modifying.

Comment: oh see now how do i lock with the ormlite?  and a concurrent thread?   is this possible if i stack a ton of activities one off each other and back out of em in an unfortunate order?

Comment: I struggled with a small detail for a while: to update properly, both adapter.add(xxx) AND adapter.notifydatasetchanged() have to be in the runnable. The more you know!