# Refresh a ListView with a cursor with new data from DB

Tags: android, database, listview, refresh, adapter

I have a problem refreshing a ListView. I call my `ListView` `Activity`, I get the data from DB with a SQL statment with a cursor, I draw the `ListView` with a custom adapter (extends `BaseAdapter`), all works fine.

I want to put an `EditText` on the top to search items on my `ListView`, filter the actual view, same Activity, with the typed text. I `getText()` from `EditText`, and make a new SQL statment filtering the results with this text. I have checked that the cursor has the correct filtered results, but I use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` trying to update the `ListView` but nothing happens (no errors or force closes).

Can anyone help me or tell me some tips to obtain this simple search function working with a database? I have found many similar questions with `ArrayLists + getFilter() + SimpleCursorAdapter`, but it doesn't works with my DB and custom adapter.

**Activity** ListaCaracteres:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(es.hsk.ap.R.layout.lista_caracteres);

    try{
        hanyuDBHelper = new HanyuSQLHelper(this);
        hanyuDB = hanyuDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        c = hanyuDB.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM Caracteres ", null);
    }
    catch(SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Toast mensajeError=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error accediendo a los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mensajeError.show();
        Log.e("LogLugares", "Error en getReadableDatabase()", ex);
    }


    adapter = new AdapterListaCaracteres(this,c);
    listaCaracteres = (ListView)findViewById(es.hsk.ap.R.id.listaCaracteres);
    listaCaracteres.setAdapter(adapter);

    buscador = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.buscador);
    buscador.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String texto="";
            texto=buscador.getText().toString();

            c = hanyuDB.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM Caracteres WHERE significado LIKE '%"+texto+"%'", null);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

My **custom adapter**, AdapterListaCaracteres extends from BaseAdapter:

```
public class AdapterListaCaracteres extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter{

private Context  mContext;
private Cursor  datos;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AdapterListaCaracteres(Context  context, Cursor  c){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.datos = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return datos.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object  getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return datos.getString(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View  getView(int position, View  convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View item = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context .LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    datos.moveToPosition(position);

    if(item==null){
        try{
            item = inflater.inflate(es.hsk.ap.R.layout.caracter, null);
        }
        catch(InflateException ex)
        {

        }


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.caracter = (TextView)item.findViewById(es.hsk.ap.R.id.caracter);
        holder.pinyin = (TextView)item.findViewById(es.hsk.ap.R.id.pinyin);
        holder.significado = (TextView)item.findViewById(es.hsk.ap.R.id.significado);

        item.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
    }           

    holder.caracter.setText(datos.getString(2));            
    holder.pinyin.setText(datos.getString(3));  
    holder.significado.setText(datos.getString(4));

    return item;

}
static class ViewHolder{
    TextView caracter;
    TextView pinyin;
    TextView significado;
}
}
```

Comment: I think this link will hwlp you... <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837397/updating-listview-by-notifydatasetchanged-has-to-use-runonuithread>

Thanks...

Comment: try extend CursorAdapter class and use this constructor http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html#CursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor,%20boolean%29

Comment: I have tried to change to CursorAdapter, ListView works ok, but it stills no refresh. I have tried requery() cursor, nothing happens, adapter.changeCursor(newCursor) throws exception "attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable", but I don't close any SQL objet... I'm surprised how difficult is to update a simply ListView :( Thanks

Comment: Also tried AsyncTask, but I don't see anything happens to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() there instead into the activity, the same. I have also run the program onto Android 2.1, 2.2, and 4.0, for a possible bug (there are a lot of questions about that, and no clear answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
 * Listener que actuará cuando se escriba en el EditText
 */
buscador.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String texto = "";
        texto = buscador.getText().toString();
        c = hanyuDB.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM Caracteres WHERE significado LIKE '%"                                                                                         + texto + "%'", null);

        AdapterListaCaracteres adapter2 = new AdapterListaCaracteres(getApplicationContext(), c, false);
        listaCaracteres.setAdapter(adapter2);
        return false;
    }

});
/*********************************************/
```

Good Luck ;)

ALEX

Answer (score 0):

Re-initialize the Adapter instead of `notifydatasetchanged():`

```
    adapter = new AdapterListaCaracteres(this,c);
    listaCaracteres.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that, I obtain a Force Close, LogCat:      


04-02 10:19:53.984: E/AndroidRuntime(565): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-02 10:19:54.004: E/AndroidRuntime(565): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 10:19:54.004: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at es.hsk.ap.caracteres.AdapterListaCaracteres.getView(AdapterListaCaracteres.java:56)
04-02 10:19:54.004: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
04-02 10:19:54.004: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1147)

Comment: then set adapter null once and then reinitialize it

Comment: I have tried to put null the adapter, but when I'm trying to setAdapter it throws the same NullPointerException. I have also tried to put ListView.setAdapter(null), and then setAdapter(adapter), but the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working! A friend of mine (Thanks Muni!) found a better way to filter a listview result dinamically with EditText:

```
buscador.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
```

instead of:

```
buscador.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
```

Thanks all people for your help.

**EDIT:**

Updating @AlexMuni and my own answer, `onKey()` method runs perfectly on emulator, but doesn't works fine in real devices.

I finally have done it perfectly with the previous method:

```
buscador = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.buscador); 
    buscador.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            texto = buscador.getText().toString();
            c = hanyuDB.rawQuery(
                    " SELECT * FROM Caracteres WHERE significado LIKE '%"
                            + texto + "%'", null);
            AdapterListaCaracteres adapter2 = new AdapterListaCaracteres(ListaCaracteres.this, c, false);
            listaCaracteres.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {
        }
    });
```